# very strange issue of entity framework5,entity framework5 bug?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a very strange issue of entity framework..

the below simple code always get the result " the value is guest"  in my develop computer,
 but it always get the result "the value is errorValue" in servers,I don't know 
 why so strange ?

```
public enum GroupPermissonType
{
    ErrorValue = 0,
    Guest = 1,
    Administrator = 3
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbContext dbContext = new DbContext("Database=testDB;Server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        GroupPermissonType result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<GroupPermissonType>("select  1 as GroupPermissonType").FirstOrDefault();

        //int value = (int)result;

        Console.WriteLine("The value is " + result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The method dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T> doesn't works fine for enum type? anybody know that? help!!

Comment: Are you certain that the binary on your 'develop computer' is the exact same as the binary on your server?

Comment: Yes,exact same,I copied the files from 'develop computer' to server.

Comment: Is the database testDB created on the default sql server instance on the server ?

Comment: The testDB will be automatically created by EF,if it not exists.

Comment: What is the .NET Framework version on your server and your box? Can it be that the server has .NET Framework 4 and your machine has .NET Framework 4.5? Enums where not supported in .NET Framework 4 so EF did not know how to handle this.